# How do I import multiple animations into the same file in Unity?

Tags: unity, maya

I have hit a major stump in my development: applying transitioning animations to the same model. I have learned how to do a single animation with keyframes, but have no clue on what to do with more than one. I tried importing different animations seperately and applying them to the same model, but it didn't work. How can I get past this stumbling block?

Comment: related http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/34726/multiple-animations-in-the-same-fbxfile.html

Comment: @Bálint, your comment helped solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring two or more animation on one object, I assume that you want to transition one animation to other. You would create states in Animator and transition states based of the parameter.

**I would recommend this tutorial:**

http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/creating-2d-animated-sprites-using-unity2d

**Note:**

This blog is for Unity2D games, but It is possible to use in Unity3D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are referring to playing two animations at the same time on a single object or simply transitioning from one animation to another, I will assume you mean transitioning from one animation to another.

The way I handle multiple animations is I get a separate file(commonly fbx) for each animation. Then, you would create states in your animator component and transition to those states based off parameters.

I would suggest reading up on animators if you have not already and follow a tutorial. There are a few good tutorials that cover animators and transitions.

Here is a Unity tutorial on the Animator controller: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/animation/animator-controller

Comment: This answer is exactly what I tried and it didn't work

Comment: In my experience if animations are not playing the animation is either not set to the same rig or does not match the rig it's applied to.
1. where were these animations made?
2. are they all made for the same rig?

Comment: I think the animations on the same rig is my problem, but I don't know how to put more than one animation on a rig.